# Selenium WebDriver proxy gets secure connection failed for firefox? in java

Tags: selenium

i am using selenium 2.53 firefox version 43 and 36 
i have set proxy to my url but whenever browser open via script, connected to  displayed at bottom of the browser but after some time secure connection failed error is displayed on the browser.

Comment: check that the proxy configuration was actually applied. to do that simply run your test again and when your browser automatically starts, stop the execution and verify the settings.

Comment: i have checked the configuration , proxy is set in network setting in firefox. but error is displayed as "connection has timed out".i have also applied pageloadtimeout parameters but issue still exists.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?